Google Cloud Data Fusion MySQL to BigQuery Pipeline Error at Execution
I have a Cloud Data Fusion pipeline for batched replication from a MySQL source to a BigQuery sink. My goal is to replicate a single table with 300 rows on a scheduled basis, and to eventually scale the number and size of the tables to replicate. The pipeline configuration is the following
{
  "name": "autoscaling-dataproc",
  "label": "Autoscaling Dataproc",
  "description": "Creates Autoscaling Dataproc clusters for program runs",
  "scope": "SYSTEM",
  "status": "ENABLED",
  "provisioner": {
    "name": "gcp-dataproc",
    "properties": [
      {
        "name": "masterMachineType",
        "value": "e2",
        "isEditable": true
      },
      {
        "name": "networkHostProjectId",
        "value": "fullcircledatondw",
        "isEditable": true
      },
      {
        "name": "network",
        "value": "default",
        "isEditable": true
      },
      {
        "name": "region",
        "value": "us-west1",
        "isEditable": true
      },
      {
        "name": "subnet",
        "value": "default",
        "isEditable": true
      },
      {
        "name": "masterNumNodes",
        "value": "1",
        "isEditable": true
      },
      {
        "name": "masterCPUs",
        "value": "2",
        "isEditable": true
      },
      {
        "name": "masterMemoryMB",
        "value": "8192",
        "isEditable": true
      },
      {
        "name": "masterDiskGB",
        "value": "1000",
        "isEditable": true
      },
      {
        "name": "workerCPUs",
        "value": "2",
        "isEditable": true
      },
      {
        "name": "workerMemoryMB",
        "value": "8192",
        "isEditable": true
      },
      {
        "name": "workerDiskGB",
        "value": "200",
        "isEditable": true
      },
      {
        "name": "workerMachineType",
        "value": "e2",
        "isEditable": true
      },
      {
        "name": "enablePredefinedAutoScaling",
        "value": "true",
        "isEditable": true
      }
    ],
    "totalProcessingCpusLabel": "Up to 84"
  },
  "created": 1732820607
}

Running a preview of the pipeline, everything works fine and the data should be replicated without issue.
Pipeline Preview Run
But when deploying the pipeline and executing it, multiple warnings and errors show in the logs and the pipeline ultimately fails.
Pipeline Deployed Run
On the detailed logs, some warnings and errors that catch my attention are the following:
12/02/2024 12:44:40
WARN
Cannot load filesystem: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem: Provider org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.HftpFileSystem not found
12/02/2024 12:44:40
WARN
Cannot load filesystem: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem: Provider org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.HsftpFileSystem not found

12/02/2024 12:44:55
WARN
spark.yarn.security.tokens.hbase.enabled is deprecated. Please use spark.security.credentials.hbase.enabled instead.
12/02/2024 12:44:55
WARN
spark.yarn.security.tokens.hive.enabled is deprecated. Please use spark.security.credentials.hive.enabled instead.

12/02/2024 12:45:26
WARN
Cannot load filesystem: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem: Provider org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.HftpFileSystem not found
12/02/2024 12:45:26
WARN
Cannot load filesystem: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem: Provider org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.HsftpFileSystem not found

12/02/2024 12:45:30
WARN
No global storagestatistics found
12/02/2024 12:45:32
WARN
Attempted to request executors before the AM has registered!
12/02/2024 12:45:56
WARN
Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources


WARN
Lost task 0.9 in stage 0.0 (TID 9) (cdap-venues-re-169ab7bd-b0cc-11ef-bdcc-4a7cc288eb0d-w-1.us-west1-a.c.fullcircledatondw.internal executor 2): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.executeTask(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:163) at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.$anonfun$write$1(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:88) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136) at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548) at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1505) at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) Caused by: org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter$AppendWriteException: org.apache.avro.UnresolvedUnionException: Not in union ["long","null"]: 3 at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter.append(DataFileWriter.java:308) at io.cdap.plugin.gcp.bigquery.sink.AvroRecordWriter.write(AvroRecordWriter.java:92) at io.cdap.plugin.gcp.bigquery.sink.AvroRecordWriter.write(AvroRecordWriter.java:38) at io.cdap.plugin.gcp.bigquery.sink.BigQueryRecordWriter.write(BigQueryRecordWriter.java:62) at io.cdap.plugin.gcp.bigquery.sink.BigQueryRecordWriter.write(BigQueryRecordWriter.java:33) at io.cdap.cdap.etl.spark.io.TrackingRecordWriter.write(TrackingRecordWriter.java:41) at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceWriteConfigUtil.write(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:368) at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.$anonfun$executeTask$1(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:138) at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1539) at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.executeTask(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:135) ... 9 more Caused by: org.apache.avro.UnresolvedUnionException: Not in union ["long","null"]: 3 at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData.resolveUnion(GenericData.java:740) at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.resolveUnion(GenericDatumWriter.java:205) at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeWithoutConversion(GenericDatumWriter.java:123) at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:75) at org.apache.avro.reflect.ReflectDatumWriter.write(ReflectDatumWriter.java:159) at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeField(GenericDatumWriter.java:166) at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumWriter.writeField(SpecificDatumWriter.java:90) at org.apache.avro.reflect.ReflectDatumWriter.writeField(ReflectDatumWriter.java:191) at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeRecord(GenericDatumWriter.java:156) at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeWithoutConversion(GenericDatumWriter.java:118) at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:75) at org.apache.avro.reflect.ReflectDatumWriter.write(ReflectDatumWriter.java:159) at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:62) at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter.append(DataFileWriter.java:302) ... 18 more


I have modified the resources of the compute profile, setting them to the limit allowed by my project. I have not found any Cloud Data Fusion related posts to the warnings and errors that I am encountering.
